# How to publish Xamarin UWP apps to windows store using VS2015?

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I cant find any information how to publish an uwp app to store which is created as xamarin.forms project. On my VS2015 proffesional version, I don't have any option as "store" as shown in this article below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Does anybody know an easy way of doing this? Most important how to handle steps 5,6,7, 10, 11 in the article if there is no automated way.

[image]

EDIT: I can find this option on the Project->Store Menu above but all the options are grayed out as shown in the image below. I am connected with a developer account email on my VS2015.

[image]

my Project is a UWP project as shown below. And I have 2nd project as WP81. Right Click on WP81 project has Store menu option enabled. problem persist only for UWP project in the same solution.

[image]

EDIT: Same project on 2 different computers.

1- has store option enabled. where I have packages below are installed
[image]

2- doesnt have store option on right click but has grayed out store menu under project has below packages are installed
[image]

Comment: Hi batmaci, in my Visual Studio 2015 enterprise Update3, I can right-click UWP project which is created as xamarin.forms project and choose Store option. Can you tell me what 's version of your Visual Studio? You can also try to [create an app package with the MakeAppx.exe tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I updated my ticket with the specific version number. I tried same project on different computer with VS 2015 enterprise installed. This one had the option but VS 2015 professional as shown in the image doesnt have the option. On the above menu Project->Store, i can find this option but all the sub menus are grayed out. as shown in the image.

Comment: Please see my update in answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please first **lest-click to select UWP or other Windows project**, and then **right-click** project and select **store** option, you can find **Create App Packages...**. If this option is disabled or does not appear at all, check that the project is a UWP project.

[image]

Comment: I updated my question also. as you can see in the image my project is UWP and WP81 project actually has store option available. I tried to reinstall UWP and also I made full repair on VS 2015 bu it didnt help

Comment: I just tried on a fresh new project and problem persist on this project as well. it looks like it is not project problem but VS.

Comment: Hi batmaci, Please create bank UWP project and right-click to select **store**, then look if  Associate App with the store and Create App Package are enable or not, Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately  it is not enabled for a new fresh project as well. I found out that it looks like that it is related to app Manifest, i am not able to open app Manifest in Design Mode although i can see as xml. But on another computer i can open the same Apo Manifest in Designer, how can i fix this? What might cause this? This looks like causing this store option problem

Comment: Hi batmaci, About this issue, I would like to suggest you to reinstall VS on your machine. Thanks.

Comment: I have just updated my question. please see the edit part. can this be something related please? I dont also understand what Deployment Kits do I need? I didnt install any of these on purpose. somehow they got installed with VS installation or updates

Comment: Hi batmaci, Please download **Windows Software Development--Windows 10.0.10586** and create blank UWP project to try again, because I find that UWP project has target version and minimum version, maybe it can be affected.